# How to make sed read exported variables

Tags: bash, awk

I'm trying to print the values of the lines associated with dates, now I will be giving an alternate code that pretty much covers what I mean

My File Contents Are:

```
2020-10-9 Sold 50 Shirts
2021-09-4
```

My Script is:

```
export x=10
sed -n '/2020-"$x"/p' < filename
```

I know I could use 10, but that's not my point here I'm trying to figure out how to use sed using an argument thats an integer.

Desired output would be

```
2020-10-9
```

Comment: `sed` *won't* read variables from the environment. What you need to do is have the shell build the `sed` script dynamically from shell variables. Whether those variables are exported or not is irrelevant.

Comment: I wouldn't use `sed` for this at all. Use `awk` instead, which *can* take arguments. `awk -v d="$x" '$0 ~ "2020-"d'`.

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Answer (score 0):

Bash dosn't interpolate variables in single quotes

Your example with double quotas works well

```sh
$ cat 1.txt 
2020-10-9 Sold 50 Shirts
2021-09-4
$ export x=10
$ sed -n "/2020-$x/p" < 1.txt 
2020-10-9 Sold 50 Shirts
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use another approach, for example with `cat` and `grep`:

```
x=10
cat 1.txt | grep 2020-$x
```

Or, as [chepner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1126841/chepner) mentioned in comment, just:

```
x=10
grep 2020-$x 1.txt
```

Comment: You don't need `cat` at all. `grep "2020-$x" 1.txt` does the same thing.

Comment: @chepner hypothetically if one were to just grep "-$x" how would you stop bash from interpreting it as an option for grep

Comment: That's what the `-e` option is for. The follow argument is *always* the pattern to use, not another possible option. `grep -e -"$x"` ...` `bash` itself has nothing to do with identifying options. It just passes arguments to `grep`, which interprets its arguments as options or not according to its internal rules.